# How to package first order partial differential equation into a module and verifying solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

$$\frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial x}=0$$

**A problem is stated as follows:**

subject to initial condition u(0,x)=Exp[-x] Sin(x)^2 and boundary condition u(t,0)=0. Solve this PDE analytically, then plot the solution for the following range of x and t : x from 0 to 3, and t from 0 to 3. Comment on the nature of the solution.

**Three questions:**

**(1)** How can I verify solution with short form of ReplaceAll function? Goal is to return True or False. **(2)** How do I fix module? Or should I use nested modules or some other construct perhaps Block?    **(3)** Am I using the If function correctly because it doesn't return True or False.

However I was successful in finding solution (but not verify it) in global scope...

```
pde = D[u[t, x], t] + D[u[t, x], x] == 0
ic = u[0, x] == Exp[-x] Sin[x]^2
bc = u[t, 0] == 0
sol = DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[t, x], {t, x}] // FullSimplify
If[u[t, x] == pde /. sol[[1]] // FullSimplify, Print["True"], Print["False"]](* did not work *)
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol[[1]]], {t, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 3}]
```

This is the module that I need to repair...

```
Module[{pde, ic, bc, sol}; pde = D[u[t, x], t] + D[u[t, x], x] == 0; 
 ic = u[0, x] == Exp[-x] Sin[x]^2; bc = u[t, 0] == 0; 
 sol = u[t, x] /. DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[t, x], {t, x}];
 If[FullSimplify[pde /. sol], Print["Verified True"], 
  Print["Verified False"]]; 
 Plot3D[{u[t, x] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 3}], Print[sol[[1]]]]
```

Comment: what is `Sin2(x)` ?

Comment: "How do I fix module?" Err. What's wrong with module? "Am I using the If function correctly because it doesn't return True or False." We cannot tell because you did not share your code. After all, this question is very incomplete. I suspect that all issues are caused by typos or syntax errors.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher sorry about that. a keyboard combination accidentally submitted question before it was completed.

Comment: what do you define a module with no API to call it? What is the point? Just for practice? Normally one defines a called module (i.e. function) that takes input as arguments and returns some result. You also need to replace `;` by `,` after the local module symbols section.

Comment: @Nasser nice catch. it was copied out of a Word document. i fixed it but it want causing the errors. please have another look at this.

Comment: @Nasser i intend to add the api afterwards but the most pressing issue i have is getting the darn module to cooperate. please show me your edits because i tried that too and i still couldnt get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of `,` and `;` had to be replaced and the `Plot3D` has to be returned with `Print`. Moreover, you used

```
sol = u[t, x] /. DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[t, x], {t, x}];
```

where you actually wanted the solution `Rule`, so I changed the line to

```
sol = DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[t, x], {t, x}];
```

Here is the corrected code

```
sol = Module[{pde, ic, bc, sol},
  pde = D[u[t, x], t] + D[u[t, x], x] == 0;
  ic = u[0, x] == Exp[-x] Sin[x]^2;
  bc = u[t, 0] == 0;
  sol = DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[t, x], {t, x}];
  If[
   FullSimplify[pde /. sol],
   Print["Verified True"],
   Print["Verified False"]
   ];
  Print[Plot3D[{u[t, x] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 3}]];
  sol[[1]]
]
```

Comment: Wonderful it worked but the If is still returning null. how can i fix it? here is what i have:

If[pde /. sol[[1]], Print[Style["Verified True", Bold, Green]], 
  Print[Style["Verified False", Bold, Red]], 
  Print[Style["Verified Unresolved", Bold, Blue]]];

Comment: The `If` returns `Null` because `Print` returns `Null`. After all, you should avoid print and store the results in separate variables or in a `List`.

Comment: tried your suggestion still returns null. could you see if i am applying the condition correctly? here is what i have: 

If[pde /. sol[[1]] // FullSimplify, ver = Style["True", Green], 
  ver = Style["False", Red], ver = Style["Null", Blue]];

Comment: What returns "null"? Really, it is important here to have complete code. "could you see if i am applying the condition correctly?" I cannot tell because I do not know what you actually want to do there... Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

This works

```
Module[{pde, ic, bc, sol, u, x, t},
 pde = D[u[t, x], t] + D[u[t, x], x] == 0;
 ic = u[0, x] == Exp[-x] Sin[x]^2;
 bc = u[t, 0] == 0;
 sol = DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[t, x], {t, x}];
 Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol[[1]]], {t, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 3}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or this

```
Module[{pde, ic, bc, sol, u, x, t},
 pde = D[u[t, x], t] + D[u[t, x], x] == 0;
 ic = u[0, x] == Exp[-x] Sin[x]^2;
 bc = u[t, 0] == 0;
 sol = First@DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[t, x], {t, x}];
 Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 3}]
 ]
```

It is better to define all symbols used as local to the module, so not
to use global one by mistake.